# How to create an object of a class which is inside a module and inherited another class?

Tags: ruby

I want to use a method c of class B. For that class A inherits class B inside the module M. Now, how can I create an object of class A and call c?

```
module M  
  class A<B  
    def C  
         puts "From A"  
    end  
  end  
   class B  
     def C  
       puts "From B"  
     end  
   end  
end
```

I am getting error " uninitialized constant M::B (NameError)"

I am unable to create object and call c like this:

```
ob=M::A.new   
ob.C
```

Comment: Where class `B` is defined? I guess ruby can't find it.

Comment: What do you mean you're "unable" to create an object like that?  What error message are you getting?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you want to use method `c` of class `B`, but in class `A` you override method `c`. What's more, if `B` is implemented, your code should work without any errors. What's exactly your purpose?

Comment: @Marek, Yes, B is implemented and in class A override method c.Now I want to create an object of A and want to call c.

Comment: @Sakib what error do you get?

Comment: @Sakib put it in question. It's completely unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @Sakib no matter how hard you try, you won't be able to make multi-line code put in the comment readable. Why don't you edit your question instead?

Comment: @Marek thnx, edited the question. Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: @Sakib I made an answer. Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implement class `A` that you want to inherit from `B` before class `B`. Change this sequence and it will work:

```
module M
  class B  
    def c
      puts "From B"  
    end  
  end
  class A < B  
    def c
      puts "From A"  
    end  
  end  
end
obj = M::A.new
ob.c
# From A
```

I also corrected method named with capital letter. It's possible, but not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this example, you are getting the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant M::B
```

So `B` is not found. As soon as you add it to your code, everything works fine:

```
class B
end

module M  
  class A < B  
    def c  
      puts "Test"
    end
  end
end

ob = M::A.new  
ob.c

# >> Test
```